# Inheritance of a base class and 2 derived classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am having all kind of difficulty getting this racer program to work. I have an abstract racer class with a abstract method and then two other classes that are derived from it.

I got an array in my main program class but errors coming up saying the `index [0]` and `[1]`

Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)

Then an error for the = sign saying
Invalid token `'='` in class, struct, or interface member declaration

The the new Racer must return a type

The main class is

```
public class Program
{
    ApplicationUtilities.DisplayApplicationInformation();
    ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Start Racer Program");
    ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Prompt for Racer information and create first Racer");

        Racer[] myarray = new Racer[2];
        myarray[0] = new Racer(HotRod);
        myarray[1] = new Racer(StreetTuner);

    public CollectRacerInformation(HotRod);
}
```

The abstract Racer class is

```
public abstract class Racer
{
    private string racerName;
    private int racerSpeed;
    private Engine engine;

    public Racer();

    public Racer(string name, int speed, Engine engine);


    Engine engine();
    public abstract bool IsDead();
}
```

My derived HotRod class is

```
public class HotRod : Racer
{
    private bool blower = true || false;

    public HotRod();

    public HotRod(string name, int speed, Engine engine);


    public override bool IsDead()
    {
        Engine engine1 = new Engine();
        engine1 = Engine1;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        rnd.NextDouble();
        bool dead = false;

        if (racerSpeed > 50 && rnd.NextDouble() > 0.6)
            if (engine1.horsePower < 300 && blower == true)
                dead = false;
            else
                dead = true;

        else if (racerSpeed > 100 && rnd.NextDouble() > 0.4)

            if (engine1.horsePower >= 300 && blower == true)
                dead = true;
            else
                dead = false;
        else
            dead = false;

        return dead;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output;

        output = "\n============ HotRod Information ============";
        output += "\n\t              Racer's Name:\t" + racerName;
        output += "\n\t               Car's Speed:\t" + carSpeed;
        output += "\n\t          Engine Cylinders:\t" + engineCylinders;
        output += "\n\t         Engine Horsepower:\t" + engineHorsePower;
        output += "n\t               Racer's Type:\t" + racerType;
        output += "n\t          Racer with Blower:\t" + carBlower;
        output += "n\t             Still Working?:\t" + IsDead;

        return output;
    }
}
```

Then my derived StreetTuner class is

```
public class StreetTuner : Racer
{
    private bool nitrous;

    public StreetTuner();

    public StreetTuner(string name, int speed, Engine engine);

    public bool IsDead
    {
        get { return IsDead; }
        set
        {
            if (speed > 50 && rnd.NextDouble() > 0.6)
                if (horsePower < 300 && blower == true)
                    IsDead = false;
                else
                    IsDead = true;
            else if (speed > 100 && rnd.NextDouble() > 0.4)
                if (horsePower >= 300 && blower == true)
                    IsDead = true;
                else
                    IsDead = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post all of your code, including the code for the entire `Racer` class. What are `HotRod` and `StreetTuner`, derived types?

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

I think you mean

```
    Racer[] myarray = new Racer[2];
    myarray[0] = new HotRod();
    myarray[1] = new StreetTuner();
```

**Updated answer**

after seeing your *actual* code, your main program needs some work.  First of all, code needs to be in *methods*, nor directly in *classes*.  Secondly, you're using *classes* as if they're *variables*.  I suspect you want something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationUtilities.DisplayApplicationInformation();
        ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Start Racer Program");
        ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Prompt for Racer information and create first Racer");

        Racer[] myarray = new Racer[2];
        myarray[0] = new HotRod();
        myarray[1] = new StreetTuner();

        CollectRacerInformation(myarray[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: To make it shorter:  `Racer[] myarray = new Racer[2] { new HotRod(), new StreetTuner() };`

Comment: Then you need to post more of your code - my assumption was that `HotRod` and `StreetTuner` derive from `Racer`.  If that is the case then you've got a syntax error somewhere else.

Comment: I have HotRod and StreetTuner as the derived classes

Comment: Post the _exact_ code that gives the error as well as the definitions of `Racer` and the derived classes; otherwise we're just wasting time by guessing what the problem is.

Comment: The the new Racer must return a type  is what the error has for        Racer

Comment: well CollectRacerInformation takes a Racer object, and then gets this information 
 Racer name, 
 Racer Speed,
 Number of cylinders in the racer's engine,
 Horsepower of the racer's engine, and  
 Nitrous or blower option on the type of Racer object

Comment: Sounds like you need to continue learning how classes, methods, and properties need to be organized.  Right now it's hard to tell what's supposed to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Derived classes have an "is-a" relationship to their base class. So in your case, a `HotRod` is a `Racer` and a `StreetTuner` is a `Racer`, therefore when you declare your array to be of type `Racer`, then anything that is a `Racer` can be put into that array, thus this:

```
var myarray = new Racer[2];
myarray[0] = new HotRod();
myarray[1] = new StreetTuner();
```

You instantiate the derived types explicitly, but through inheritance they can be used wherever their base type is specified, because they are that type (base class of `Racer`) as well as their concrete type (`HotRod` or `StreetTuner` as the case may be).

You need to write your `Racer` constructors, like this:

```
// Default constructor
public Racer()
{

}

// Named value constructor
public Racer(string _name, int _speed, Engine _engine)
{
    // Store the name, speed and engine values
    racerName = _name; 
    racerSpeed = _speed; 
    engine = _engine;
}
```

Same goes for `HotRod` and `StreetTuner` constructors as well.

Comment: You have written your constructors wrong, see my updated answer.